# ¿Cómo implementar las condicionales v-if en vue correctamente?

Tags: vue.js

tengo un formulario en para registrar mensajes en Laravel y Vue, donde estoy tratando de validar si es que los campos están vacíos, me aparezca el botón de guardar y si fuese lo contrario que me aparezca el botón de actualizar, los campos lo lleno desde mi base de datos, tengo un problema ya que no me aparecen los botones, quisiera que me ayuden en eso, gracias de antemano, este es mi código:

```
            <div>
                <div>                       
                    <form v-on:submit.prevent="storeMensajeria()">
                    <div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12" v-if="tipo == 'bienvenida'" >
                                <div class="row">
                                   
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 mt-1">
                                        <label>CORREO SALIENTE: </label>
                                        <input type="text" v-model="mensajeria.correo_saliente_bien" 
                                        class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>                                      
                                      <div class="col-sm-12 mt-1">
                                        <label>MENSAJE: </label>
                                        <textarea v-model="mensajeria.mensaje_bien" class="form-control" 
                                        rows="10" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                   
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div>
                            <div v-if="estado_mensajes == 'ACTUALIZAR'">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn" >EDITAR</button>
                            </div>
                            <div v-if="estado_mensajes == 'NUEVO'">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">CREAR</button>
                            </div>
                           
                       </div>
                    </form>
                </div>    
            </div>
```

-- Script

```
estadoMensajes(){
            if(this.mensajeria.correo_saliente_bien !== ''){
                this.estado_mensajes == 'ACTUALIZAR'
            }else{
                this.estado_mensajes == 'NUEVO'
            }
        },
        storeMensajeria(){
            if(this.estado_mensajes == 'NUEVO'){
                axios.post('/store-mensajeria', this.mensajeria).then((response)=>{
                toastr.success('Mensajeria registrada');
                this.getMensajeria();   
                      
            }
            else{
                axios.post('/update-mensajeria', this.mensajeria).then((response)=>{
                toastr.success('Mensajeria actualizada');
                this.getMensajeria();
            } 
        },
```

Comment: Creo que tu `template` está un poco cortado, puedes agregar el resto? solo para que cierren los divs

Comment: Ya la edite....

Answer (score 0):

En tu función `estadoMensajes` no estás haciendo una asignación, reemplazala por:

```
estadoMensajes() {
    if (this.mensajeria.correo_saliente_bien !== '') {
        this.estado_mensajes = 'ACTUALIZAR'
    } else {
        this.estado_mensajes = 'NUEVO'
    }
}
```

Antes solo tenías `this.estado_mensajes == 'ACTUALIZAR'`, lo cual no asignaba un nuevo valor pero `this.estado_mensajes` siempre era `'NUEVO'`